# Predefined role(s) to use in PostgreSQL in order to create a login role with privileges to automate database development

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-administration, amazon-aurora

I am in the process of setting up an `AWS Aurora (PostgreSQL) 15.x` instance for a Java-based application. I only have access to the instance through the `rds_superuser` account — not `psql`.

I am configuring three *login roles* initially:

1. A read-only `user_ro` login role — based on `pg_read_all_data`.
2. A read/write `user_rw` login role — based on `pg_read_all_data` and `pg_write_all_data`.
3. A `user_liquibase` login role with privileges to automate database development by doing schema changes, seed data.

However, I'm unsure of what predefined role I can use for `user_liquibase` that allows me to `create` and/or `drop` database objects. I would prefer to configure `user_liquibase` like `user_rw` by granting it `pg_read_all_data` and `pg_write_all_data` privileges, but I'm missing the rest of the privileges necessary for these tasks.

Can anyone suggest a predefined role to accomplish this?

> I am not familiar with these tasks as I am more on the development side, but this time I need to set up the instance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_write_all_data` allows you to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on all existing tables.

To create an object, you need to have the `CREATE` privilege on the schema where you create the object.

To drop an object, you must be the owner of the object or a member of the owning role.